# Local environment not set in MPI process

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, mpi, bash

When I run `mpiexec` on a few computers some of them don't automatically load their local environments - they don't seem to run their `bashrc` or `bash_profile` files. When I `ssh` into these troublesome computers everything is fine (the environment is all there). What else could be missing?

If I run

```
mpiexec -np 1 --host remotehost printenv
```

I get a very small result. However if I do the following

```
ssh remotehost
printenv
```

I get a much larger and more comprehensive result. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is not read by non-interactive shells. Check for differences in the system wide environment directories in `/etc/<distro and shell-specific location>`.

Comment: I find that it is easier to let the MPI launcher set the environment variables.  With OpenMPI this is the `-x` option to `mpiexec`.  MPICH2's launcher uses `-env`.

Answer (score 0):

MPI jobs run in non-interactive shells which do not load `.bashrc`.  Rather than having each job load its own `.bashrc`, it is usually better to set the environment variables in the call to mpiexec.  MPICH will pass all environment variables from the launching process by default, but with OpenMPI you need to use the `--envall` option.